# Printing the first N terms from a telescoping series

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, loops

I would like to produce a LaTeX document that generates the first N terms of the telescoping series sum(1/k-1/(1+k)) where k=1,2,3...,N, such that it displays at least the first 10 terms.
I want the output in the form (1-1/2)+(1/2-1/3)+.....+(1/10-1/11)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 12):

The difficulty is not in producing it, but rather in *printing* it.

Here's a way; for printing ten terms we need two lines and I decided to let TeX bother with the splitting. The `\telescope` command is generic, by redefining `\Term` you can print other similar series.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,amsmath}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\telescope}{m}
 {
  \Term{1}
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 2 } { 1 } { #1 }
   {
    +\Term{##1}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\Term}[1]{%
  {\biggl(
  \ifnum#1=1
    1
  \else
    \dfrac{1}{#1}
  \fi
  -
  \dfrac{1}{\number\numexpr#1+1}
  \biggr)}
}

\begin{document}
Here are ten terms
\[
\begin{minipage}{.9\displaywidth}
\linespread{2.5}\selectfont
\raggedright
\leftskip=2em\hspace*{-2em}
$
\telescope{10}
$
\end{minipage}
\]
and here are twenty-five
\[
\begin{minipage}{.9\displaywidth}
\linespread{2.5}\selectfont
\raggedright
\leftskip=2em\hspace*{-2em}
$
\telescope{25}
$
\end{minipage}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

egreg just got there first but:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\term[1]{%
{(\ifnum#1=1 1 \else\frac{1}{#1}\fi
 -
 \frac{1}{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax})}}

\newcommand\xsum[1]{%
\term{#1}%
\ifnum#1<10
+
\expandafter\xsum\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}%
\fi}


\begin{document}
$
\xsum{1}
$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is another answer to propose an alternative to the very good egreg's answer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{temp}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

$\sum_{k=1}^N \left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1} \right) = \left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)
\foreach \n in {2,...,10}
{\setcounter{temp}{\n}\stepcounter{temp} +\left(\frac{1}{\n}-\frac{1}{\arabic{temp}} \right)}
+\dots+\left(\frac{1}{N}-\frac{1}{N+1}\right)$

\end{document}
```

It is based on a `\foreach` loop from the `pgffor` package.

And here is its output

[image: Output]

**EDIT** Using Tobi's tips a better version of the MWE would be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

$\sum_{k=1}^N \left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1} \right) = \left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)
\foreach \n [remember=\n as \lastn (initially 2)] in {3,...,11} 
{+\left(\frac{1}{\lastn}-\frac{1}{\n} \right)}
+\dots+\left(\frac{1}{N}-\frac{1}{N+1}\right)$

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\foreach`’s `remember=\n as \lastn` option and then `\frac{1}{\lastn}-\frac{1}{\n}` instead of the additional counter … Furthermore `\dots` should be used instead of three dots `...` and a code formatting with some line breaks would be nice ;-)